# What should be the kernel size for deviation of 0.5

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

The implementation asked me to remove noise by applying Gaussian blur ( sigma = 0.5 ), but didn't mention anything about kernel size. Now, I am confused what kernel size should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gaussian formula has no actual endpoint, it goes on to infinity. It's up to you to determine the point at which you can cut it off without affecting the results.

For image processing you can almost certainly cut it off at the point where the formula reaches 1/256 or less. For a sigma of 0.5 this is 1.4833; since the kernel coordinates are whole numbers that means you can truncate to 1. This means the kernel has to go +/- 1 from the center, or 3x3.